# Capture high resolution frames but view smaller resolution

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-camera

i wanna capture a high resolution frames from device's camera - like Tablet - and stream it to other device

i need to view the captured frames on the current device - Tablet - smaller in resolution than streamed one - which is streamed in high resolution - to make the best use of the screen space

the problem im facing is that asks camera for high video resolution via

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(VGA_WIDTH, VGA_HEIGHT);
```

it get viewed as fullsize SurfaceView and i tried to scale it, frames was sent as rubbish
and found that 
Camera.PreviewCallback used to deliver copies of preview frames as they are displayed

is there any way to separate the capturing from the viewing of frames